# Como unir los resultados de 3 iteraciones

Tags: java, jsoup

Tengo estos 3 for, como puedo hacerlo para intercalar los resultados, me explico que vaya el nombre, con el link y el valor, y as sucesivamente, ya que ahora los imprimo y salen por separado.

```
    for (Element nombre : nombre1) {

        System.out.println("Nombre:" + nombre.text());

    }

    for (Element link : links1) {

        System.out.println("link:" + link.attr("href"));

    }

    for (Element valor : valor1) {

        System.out.println("valor:" + valor.text());

    }
```

Comment: Si los arreglos tienen misma longitud, haz un for simple.

Comment: no tienen la misma longitud, debo intercalar los 3 resultados.

Comment: Si no tienen la misma longitud, entonces nada más haz un check que el índice esté dentro de los boundaries del arreglo. ¿Puedes proporcionar un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: Claro, con jsoup debo intentar obtener 3 registros de una página de compras, el link el nombre y el valor, ya obtuve estos valores pero por separados, en 3 variables cada una, lo que debo hacer es que cada link, nombre y valor al imprimirlo estén en una sola fila o columna,

Comment: Ok, bueno pues sí, creo que la idea de hacer un for simple es idónea para lo que quieres hacer

Comment: pero amigo como lo hago

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla (en mi humilde opinión) es con un ciclo for sencillo, como el siguiente

```
String[] hola = {"hola", "mundo", "ja", "ja"};
String[] adios = {"adiós", "mundo", "cruel", "ja", "ji"};
String[] nose = {"no sé", "qué", "poner", "aquí", "esto", "está", "de relleno"};

// seleccionar el arreglo de mayor tamaño
String[] largerArray = hola.length > adios.length && hola.length > nose.length
    ? hola
    : adios.length > nose.length ? adios : nose;

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
for (int i = 0; i < largerArray.length; ++i) {
    if (i < hola.length)
        strBuilder.append(hola[i]);

    strBuilder.append(',');
    if (i < adios.length)
        strBuilder.append(adios[i]);

    strBuilder.append(',');
    if (i < nose.length)
        strBuilder.append(nose[i]);
    strBuilder.append(lineSeparator);
}

System.out.println(strBuilder);
```

Dado que mencionas que los arreglos no tienen el mismo tamaño, hay que seleccionar el arreglo más largo e iterar sobre todos sus elementos.

A la par que hacemos eso verificamos en los otros arreglos (de menor o igual tamaño), que el índice `i` todavía es menor a la longitud del arreglo (de lo contrario obtendríamos una excepción). Y si es ese el caso, agregar el elemento a la fila (en este caso al `stringBuilder`).

Y listo, así puedes juntar los 3 elementos en una sola línea. En este caso el `String` lo construí como si fuera un `.csv` como podrás ver. Pero realmente eso no es lo importante.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la respuesta, lo probare y te comento como me fue. de ante mano muchas gracias